# AIC and transformation of the independent variable

Tags: data-transformation, model-selection, aic

I set up different models: always same dependent variable and dataset, only the independent variable changes. All model assumptions are fullfilled.

Now i do a model selection with the AIC. I look at the model with an independent variable without and with a log transformation. The model with the log transformed dependend variable *a* has a lower AIC.
Then i look at variable *b* and here the untransformed variable has a lower AIC.
In total i  look at 14 independend variables and the log transformation shows lower AIC for 6 of them.

My question is if i should use only log transformed or only not transformed data or just decide it for each variable after looking at the AIC?

Comment: Nice question. Could you add 1-2 formulas for the AIC computation, just to clarify?

Comment: I used the `AIC()` command in R-Studio: [RDocumentation Link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/AIC)